# Get Top Performer by Subgroup Using Index and Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to rank names in Column C from largest to smallest score.

```
Category    Score   Name        Total Rank  Apple Rank  Orange Rank
Apple   10  Joe     Rachel  Rachel  0
Orange  15  Don     Natalie 0   Natalie
Apple   20  James       Tom Tom 0
Apple   1   Rob     Nothing Nothing 0
Orange  3   Mary        Gina    0   Gina
Orange  100 Rachel      James   0   James
Orange  99  Natalie     Don 0   Don
Orange  87  Tom     Joe 0   Joe
Apple   27  Gina        Mary    Mary    0
Orange  30  Nothing     Rob 0   Rob
```

This works in Column E for Apples AND Oranges, with formula in E2 that is

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$25,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$25=LARGE($B$2:$B$25,ROWS(E$1:E1)))*(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$C$2:$C$25)=0),),0))
```

**However, the goal is to compare Apples to Apples and Oranges to Oranges.**
Only, the formulas in Columns F and G show "0" values for those rows that aren't in the right Apple/Orange category.

For F2:

=IF($A:$A="Apple",INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B:$B=LARGE($B:$B,ROWS(F$1:F1)))*(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,$C:$C)=0),),0)),0)

For G2:

=IF($A:$A="Orange",INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B:$B=LARGE($B:$B,ROWS(G$1:G1)))*(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,$C:$C)=0),),0)),0)

How do I modify the codes so that 0 values won't show up?
Something like this would be great: (screenshot made by just copy pasting values...)

```
Apple Rank  Orange Rank
Rachel  Natalie
Tom Gina
Nothing James
Mary    Don
    Joe
    Rob
```

Comment: Could you just replace all instances of `,0` in your formula with `,""`, or does that not achieve what you want?

Comment: =IF($A:$A="Apple",INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B:$B=LARGE($B:$B,ROWS(F$1:F2)))*(COUNTIF(F$1:F2,$C:$C)=0),)," "))," ") --- This formula still shows an empty row.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Unless the whole column ranges are required the steps below may seem to take an uncomfortably long time if these ranges are not restricted.

Assuming you have what below is in ColumnA:G and a corresponding layout:

[image]

then ColumnsI:J may be achieved quite simply by copying ColumnF:G and Paste Special..., Values into I1, then select ColumnsI:J, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Replace..., Find what: `0`, Replace with: , Replace All followed by Find & Select, Go To Special..., select Blanks (only), OK, right-click on one of the chosen cells and Delete..., Shift cells up, OK.

To remove the `0`s from ColumnF:G only replacing the final `0` in each formula with `""` is sufficient.